# moment JS get name of the day in different language

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the name of the day in French using Moment.js

```
moment("01-06-2018").locale("Fr").format("dddd")
```

This returns "`Saturday`" whereas I want to get the name of the day in French

Comment: Do you include the MomentJS file with locales, or without locales?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you have imported `fr` locale and do not use [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) with non ISO 8601 inputs, use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead.

As [locale docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) says:

> By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use.

In the browser, you can use both `moment/locale/fr.js` (French localization) file or use `moment-with-locales.js` file that includes each locale setting supported by moment, see moment [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/) for other environments.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log(moment("01-06-2018", 'MM-DD-YYYY').locale("fr").format("dddd"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the proper file is included.

```
moment("01-06-2018").lang("Fr").format("dddd");
```

```js
var res = moment("01-06-2018", 'MM-DD-YYYY').locale("Fr").format("dddd");
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```