# Moment locale not working - getting values in English

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to set the language of moment in a function, like this:

```
moment.locale('nb');
const fraDato = moment('2018-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMMM');
const tilDato = moment('2018-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMMM');
const months = moment.months();
const fromIndex = months.findIndex(month => month === fraDato);
const toIndex = months.findIndex(month => month === tilDato) + 1;

const range = months.slice(fromIndex, toIndex);

console.log(range);
```

I get the returned values in English.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yjt1gfs/3/) for it.
How can I make this work with local set to different language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment JS get name of the day in different language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853874/moment-js-get-name-of-the-day-in-different-language)

Comment: The issue is that you have to import `nb` locale (or use `moment-with-locales.js`). The suggested dupe has a similar sample with `fr` locale.

Answer (score 0):

You have it misspelled. It should be `moment.locale('nd');`.

Check it [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/).

Comment: Oh, now I see that, but even with the correct locale function, I still get English language.

Comment: You must import the file with the translation. I usually do it like this `import 'moment/locale/nb';` or require. Depends if you are using ES6.